# Can I change a child class's variable and return it using the parent class's function

Tags: c++, oop

So I have a parent class Transport and a child class Horse.

The parent class has a virtual function go() which the child uses to let the child object know how far to travel.

The parent class also has a method called get_dist_travelled() which returns the total distance travelled, but when called for the child object I noticed that the value hasen't been changed and it just returns 0.

Not sure if I am returning the right variable/not sure how to return the value I want/not sure even if I can do that (Without changing the fucntion's parameter)

Transport.h

```
class Transport{

private:
    int kms;
    int kmsAll;
public:

    Transport();
    int get_dist_travelled();
    void virtual go();

};
```

Transport.cpp

```
Transport::Transport(){     
}

int Transport::get_dist_travelled(){
    return kmsAll;      
}

void Transport::go(){
    kmsAll=kmsAll+kms;
}
```

Horse.h

```
class Horse: public Transport{
private:
    int kms;
    int kmsAll;
public:
    Horse();
    void go(int kms);

};
```

Horse.cpp

```
Horse::Horse():Transport(){
    kmsAll=0;
}

void Horse::go(int kms){
    kmsAll=kmsAll+kms;
    cout<<"The object has Traveled "<<kms<< " kms"<<endl;
}
```

Comment: The member variables of `Transport` and `Horse` are completely unrelated; they only happen to have the same names.

Comment: So there is no way I can use a variable initialised in the child class in the parent class? @molbdnilo

Comment: A base class can't use any variable that's defined in a derived class, since it doesn't know that they exist. It's impossible to solve this with the given interface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your horse has two sets of members. Those inherited from `Transport` named `kms` and `kmsAll` and those defined in its class definition called `kms` and `kmsAll`.

The members of `Horse` are shadowing those inherited from `Transport`. Hence in methods of `Transport` you are working on members of `Transport` and in methods of `Horse` you are working on members of `Horse`.

Instead of repeating the members from `Transport` in `Horse` the base class should grant access to them when the derived class needs access. Either provide `public` / `protected` getters or make the member itself `protected` (`public` not remcommended).

For example (the virtual method is fine, so I skip it for the example):

```
class transport {
    protected:
     int total_kms;
};

class horse : public transport {
     void run(int km) {  total_kms += km; }
};                    // ^^ this is transport::total_kms
```

---

And here is an example that demonstrates what happens in your code:

```
#include <iostream>

struct transport {
  int a = 1;
  int b = 2;
};

struct horse : public transport {
  int a = 42;
  int b = 100;
  void set() {
    transport::a += 1;
    transport::b += 1;
    a -= 1;
    b -= 1;
  }
};

int main() {
  horse h;
  std::cout << h.a << "\n";
  std::cout << h.b << "\n";
  std::cout << h.transport::a << "\n";
  std::cout << h.transport::b << "\n";
  h.set();
  std::cout << h.a << "\n";
  std::cout << h.b << "\n";
  std::cout << h.transport::a << "\n";
  std::cout << h.transport::b << "\n";
}
```

[Output](https://godbolt.org/z/jWeMvfTox):

```
42
100
1
2
41
99
2
3
```

Usually you want to avoid shadowing (two variables with same name in scope -> only one of them is directly accessible). When you have class members shadowing inherited members you can still access them by using their full name (eg `h.transport::a` accesses `transport::a` in `h`, actually not the "full name").